# Download video file to a specific folder from Google Drive using authorization in android

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to build an app where i want to download a video file from google drive and save it to my app folder. Now i have followed all the steps for authorizing the app into google console and i am using [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) instruction from google to download the video.

This is how i have used my googleclient object,

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addApi(Plus.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
```

this is my Asynctask code,

```
private class fetchVideo extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL url = null;
            int count;
            try {
                url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(yoActivity.this, accountName, Constants.SCOPE));
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                //you will recive the file in input stream
                File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File file = new File(sdcard, "/VideoLooperFolder/randomVid.mp4");

                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;

                while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                }
                fileOutput.close();

            } catch (IOException | GoogleAuthException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

i am using this Scope, `SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"`. But i am getting a `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)` exception.

Am i using a wrong scope? Please any kind of help would be necessary!!

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) you've given, be noted that downloading the file requires the user to have at least read access. Additionally, your app must be authorized with a scope that allows reading of file content.

It is also stated in this [link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth) that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` is deprecated and must be replaced with the equivalent [profile](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#profile) scope.

> Note: This scope is deprecated; however, it will be maintained and kept available for backward compatibility. For an explanation about this change, see [Migrating to Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/auth-migration#timetable).